# Regexp - Match re-occurring pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a recursive url which can have an infinite amount of ids after the first `/pages` bit:

```
/pages/987d6fg8976df898dsa/92834799437324834/923897439874202307/.....
```

And so on and so on..

As well as have `/new` or `/edit` at the end like:

```
/pages/987d6fg8976df898dsa/92834799437324834/923897439874202307/new
/pages/987d6fg8976df898dsa/92834799437324834/923897439874202307/edit
```

I need to match these recursive urls, so I came up with these regexp's:

/new:

```
^\/pages\/[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,}/new$
```

/edit:

```
^\/pages\/[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,}/edit$
```

The problem here is that it only matches strings that have one id string, so `/pages/93848347s7a87sa9ds7d` works but `/pages/20839283792839289d/023898473947384349` fails.

I've tried looking for a regexp which solves this but I haven't come across any which suits my needs.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Split by `/` and remove empty elements and `pages`, `new` & `edit` from the resulting array.

Comment: `^/pages/[a-zA-Z0-9/-]*/new$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this

```
^\/pages\/[a-zA-Z0-9-\/]{0,}\/new$
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use:

```
/^\/pages\/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]*\/)*(new|edit)$/
```

```js
var test = [
    '/pages/987d6fg8976df898dsa/92834799437324834/923897439874202307/new',
    '/pages/987d6fg8976df898dsa/92834799437324834/923897439874202307/edit'
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a+' :'+/^\/pages\/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]*\/)*(new|edit)$/.test(a);
}));
```